# Java - How to "refresh" key event and call it again inside a while loop

Tags: java, actionlistener, keyevent

The problem is not exactly as simple as I will describe, but the paradigm is kind of similar. So, let's say I made this method with a while loop that will keep running as long as value of x < 100. And x will increment by 1 only if the spacebar is pressed. How exactly would I do that?

What I wrote is the following:

```
public void keyPressed(String key){
    //assume that x = 0
    while(x < 100){
        if(key.equals("Space")){
            x += 1;
        }
    }
}
```

I know, I know. My code will continuously increment x even with just one press of the spacebar. That's because the value of key will remain the same throughout the loop. What needs to be done is "refresh" the value of key, and trigger another key event by pressing the space bar. I don't have any idea how to do that though. Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

`keyPressed` is defined in another class as:

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    String key = KeyEvent.getKeyText(e.getKeyCode());
    for (GameObject go : gameobjects) {
        go.keyPressed(key);
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks like you want to create a game. Do you use some kind of framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The loop must run in a different thread from the thread where you listen for KeyEvent.
The KeyEvent listener, when invoked, must change a property in the other class so that the thread can test it in each iteration of the loop.

```
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

public class MainLoop {

 private final AtomicInteger x = new AtomicInteger(0);

 public void startLoop() {
    Runnable runnable = () -> {
        while (x.get() < 100) {
            // Do stuff...
        }
    };

    // start the thread
    new Thread(runnable).start();
 }

 public void keyPressed(String key) {
    if (key.equals("Space")) {
        x.incrementAndGet();
    }
 }

}

public class KeyListener {

 public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    String key = KeyEvent.getKeyText(e.getKeyCode());
    for (GameObject go : gameobjects) {
        go.keyPressed(key);
    }
 }

}
```

Please note that the property shared between threads must be thread safe (for a String you can use the AtomicReference class from java.util.concurrent.atomic package)

To manage the threads, better to use the JDK thread executors [Oracle Executors Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/executors.html)